# MacOS x86_64 error with C/assembly language file: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 when compiling/linking assembly

Tags: c, macos, assembly, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile this file from an open-source git repo:

https://github.com/xcist/main/blob/master/gecatsim/clib_build/src/p_nlog_inline.c

I'm on the MacOS x86_64 platform. OS v13.4

I can compile that file without errors using this command:

g++ -O0 -g -Wall -static -msse -masm=intel -fPIC -c p_nlog_inline.c

Using the MacOS specific Makefile:
https://github.com/xcist/main/blob/master/gecatsim/clib_build/MakeMacOS
when I try to link the .o file along with the rest of the .o files, I get these errors:

```
make -f ../MakeMacOS libcatsim_macos.so
............................................. 
Building system-specific library ..... 
        
g++ -Wall -fPIC -O0 -static-libstdc++ -o libcatsim_macos.so -shared MatVec.o BaseObject.o ClipPlane.o Transformation.o Intersection.o Interpolate.o main.o Photon.o CrossSectionHandler.o Volume.o Detector.o CrossSection.o Phantom.o DD3Proj.o DD3Proj_roi_notrans_mm.o voxelized_projector.o getMemorySize.o negative_log.o gemsfilt.o pd3dbpsemi.o DD2Back.o DD2Proj.o DD2WBack.o DD3WBack.o pd2dbpcurved.o pd2dbpflat.o extractsino.o viewshift.o spline.o xybowtie.o DD2ParProj.o analytic_projector.o rndpoi.o nCAT_main.o fm_gethostid.o fm_getrandpid.o p_nlog_inline.o -fPIC  
        
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-static-libstdc++' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] 
        
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   
    "_p_nlog_inline", referenced from:
              nlog(float*, float*, int) in negative_log.o   
    "and_mask", referenced from:
              repeat in p_nlog_inline.o   
    "coeff1", referenced from:
              repeat in p_nlog_inline.o   
    "coeff2", referenced from:
              p_nlog_inline(float*, float*, int) in p_nlog_inline.o   
    "coeff3", referenced from:
              repeat in p_nlog_inline.o   
    "coeff4", referenced from:
              p_nlog_inline(float*, float*, int) in p_nlog_inline.o   
    "coeff5", referenced from:
              p_nlog_inline(float*, float*, int) in p_nlog_inline.o   
    "coeff6", referenced from:
              p_nlog_inline(float*, float*, int) in p_nlog_inline.o   
    "coeff7", referenced from:
              repeat in p_nlog_inline.o   
    "coeff8", referenced from:
              repeat in p_nlog_inline.o   
    "exp_mult", referenced from:
              repeat in p_nlog_inline.o   
    "exp_sub", referenced from:
              repeat in p_nlog_inline.o   
    "or_mask", referenced from:
              p_nlog_inline(float*, float*, int) in p_nlog_inline.o 
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) 
    make: *** [libcatsim_macos.so] Error 1
```

I tried several things based on online recommendations. I've been able to get it to compile the .o files but I am stuck at this linking stage. Any ideas on what to do next?

[UPDATED]: The symbols are defined in the corresponding .h file which is here:

https://github.com/xcist/main/blob/master/gecatsim/clib_build/src/p_nlog_inline.h

Comment: Enable optimizations if they are inline

Comment: Where are these symbols defined (implemented)? In an assembler file? In a C source file?  In a library?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I updated the post to reflect where the symbols are defined.

Comment: I assume the compiler is now smart enough to remove the unused constants even when not optimizing. It was bad trying to rely on that not happening to start with. Also this is quite bad inline asm.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is so old that I don't even know where it came from.

Comment: If you just want it to compile then remove that `p_nlog_inline` and `#define p_nlog_inline p_nlog` Maybe the non-inline version is fast enough for your purposes.

Comment: The output of your compilation command is defaulting to something not picked up by the makefile...  you need to add `-o p_nlog_inline.o` to the compilation flags.

Answer (score 0):

Error is the line：

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -O0 -static-libstdc++ -o libcatsim_macos.so -shared MatVec.o BaseObject.o ClipPlane.o Transformation.o Intersection.o Interpolate.o main.o Photon.o CrossSectionHandler.o Volume.o Detector.o CrossSection.o Phantom.o DD3Proj.o DD3Proj_roi_notrans_mm.o voxelized_projector.o getMemorySize.o negative_log.o gemsfilt.o pd3dbpsemi.o DD2Back.o DD2Proj.o DD2WBack.o DD3WBack.o pd2dbpcurved.o pd2dbpflat.o extractsino.o viewshift.o spline.o xybowtie.o DD2ParProj.o analytic_projector.o rndpoi.o nCAT_main.o fm_gethostid.o fm_getrandpid.o p_nlog_inline.o -fPIC
```

Correct use is like:

```
gcc -fPIC -somethingElse -c name.c -lXXXXXXXX -lXXXXXX
sudo ld -x --shared -o /lib/XXXXX/XXXXXXXX.so  XXXXXX.o -lXXXXXX -lXXXXXX
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Shows even more errors about undefined symbols.

Comment: @hikerjobs Can you explain in detail how you operated? `/lib/XXXXX/XXXXXXXX.so`  directory may be other, it just example.

Comment: `undefined symbols` means when you `gcc` or `ld` missing something.

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation, it turns out that I had to add a _ (underscore) in front of those variables that were throwing up errors. For example, _coeff1 instead of coeff1.
Something to do with the way MacOS handles it. Weird.

Comment: Yeah, some platforms decorate C symbols with leading underscores.  That's one way to make sure you never have ambiguity between register names and global var names like `int eax` or `int r0`, although most asm syntaxes either avoid the problem entirely (like AT&T) or have optional syntax to disambiguate (like NASM).  Anyway, macOS does leading underscores, Linux ELF doesn't for most / all targets.  Ancient Linux a.out did.  Windows x64 doesn't, Windows x86 (32-bit) does.